# Multiply given argument by 3 within a template function (C++)

Tags: c++, function, templates

I am trying to "multiply" a given string by 3 - which is passed to a template function.

I am getting the error message:
'initializing' cannot convert from 'T' to  'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator<char'

```
template <typename T>
std::string bythree(T argument) {

  std::string message = "";
  
  if (typeid(argument) == typeid(std::string)) {
    std::string mul_str = argument + argument + argument;
    message = mul_str;
  }
}
```

I get this when I use the logic of `std::string message = argument + argument + argument;`

Any help on the logic to use behind this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: How are you calling `bythree`?

Comment: I am defining a string in my main function that I want to pass. Then just cout-ing bythree(said string).

Answer (score 4):

No matter what type you use, it still needs to compile. So, if you pass an `int`, it will try to assign an int to that string and fail.

To do a type test like you're doing, there's a few ways. You can make a default template version that works for all types, and a non-template overload that has your specific type. The compiler will prefer the non-template overload when applicable:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string bythree(T argument) {
  return "not a string";
}

std::string bythree(std::string argument) {
  return argument + argument + argument;
}
```

You can also instead *specialize* the template. You provide an "exception" for a specific type of T:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string bythree(T argument) {
  return "not a string";
}

template<>
std::string bythree<std::string>(std::string argument) {
  return argument + argument + argument;
}
```

You can use `enable_if` with type traits to enable types of T with specific traits:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, int>::type = 0>
typename std::string bythree(T argument) {
  return "not a string";
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, int>::type = 0>
typename std::string bythree(T argument) {
  return argument + argument + argument;
}
```

In C++17, you can combine type traits and `if constexpr` do type testing in-line inside the function like you're trying to do:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string bythree(T argument) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
    return argument + argument + argument;
  } else {
    return "not a string";
  }
}
```

This works where `typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)` doesn't, because the compiler won't try to compile the contents of the `if constexpr` block if the condition isn't true (evaluated at compile-time).