# c++ deciding the dynamic template type

Tags: c++, templates

Inside a template function, is there any way that I can tell the type of the template being used. I'd like to do something as follows:

For example:

```
template <typename T>
void function(T t) {
    if (T instancof int)     auto object = IntObject();
    else if (T instanceof string)    auto object = StringObject();
}
```

IntObject and StringObject are just two different types.
If this function is applied as follows:

```
function<int>(5)
```

I'd like to construct an instance of IntObject

The Concrete code is as follows:

```
bool not_null = true;
if (key instanceof uint64_t) {
    auto object = ObjectWithUInt64Key();
else if (key instanceof std::string) {
    auto object = ObjectWithStringKey();

auto result = get<CascadeType>(key,ver,subgroup_index,shard_index);
for (auto& reply_future:result.get()) {
    object = reply_future.second.get();
    ver = object.previous_version_by_key; 
    not_null = not_null && !object.is_null();
}
if (not_null) 
    return object;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic type". Also, what is `InstInstance`, and `StringInstance`?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You probably want to clarify your question a bit. Is `IntObject` one of your classes? What do you want to do with it once it's constructed?

Comment: @super let me know if the concrete example still doesn't make sense

Comment: You're asking two different questions: For "how to I test a function template's type", does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64254612/1863938 . And for "How can I store different types in the same object", check out [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or a [virtual base class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you need is to make a `CreateObjectWithKey` template function, then add some full specialization to it.

```
template <typename T>
auto CreateObjectWithKey();

template <>
auto CreateObjectWithKey<int>() {
    return ObjectWithIntKey();
}

template <>
auto CreateObjectWithKey<std::string>() {
    return ObjectWithStringKey();
}
```

Then you can use it as follows

```
template <typename T>
void function(T t) {
    auto object = CreateObjectWithKey<T>();
}
```